# How can I create a django restframework?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm a beginner in "Python".I would like to know every details about
"Django restframework" and I followed some beginner tutorial
videos.But I can't understand the "API" portion.Is there any need for
creating another project file/folder for django restframework?

Answer (score 0):

Have you go through doc.

[Django restframework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org)

If you are familiar with virtual environment then it will be easy for you to understand..

And there is no need to add new folder/file for same..